# AlterColumn fails for indexed properties on db migration in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following Entity for which I have successfully created the table in my db. Now on migration I am changing the 'CreatedOn' column to have default value.But every time I run the Alter command I get the following Error.

**Entity**

```
public class MyTeam
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("OwnerId_CreatedOn", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [Index("OwnerId_CreatedOn", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public virtual Owner MyOwner { get; set; }

}
```

**Alter Command on DbMigrations Up method**

```
AlterColumn("MyTeam", "CreatedOn", n => n.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "SYSUTCDATETIME()"));
```

**Error while running the Update-Database**

```
The index 'OwnerId_CreatedOn' is dependent on column 'CreatedOn'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN CreatedOn failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Comment: That colum is indexed. You should remove the index, alter colum and re-create index

Comment: @mineto i tried that as well but no luck

Comment: got it the DropColumn("TableName","indexName") , in-place of the indexName i was passing the column name. Thanks @Admir Tuzović https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862208/how-to-drop-unique-index-with-entity-framework-code-first-migrations