# Why is an index created more than one time in SQL via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, indexing

I have written a service, which imports every night more than 960.000 rows to a SQL Database. This data will be used for other operations few hours later.
The application is a .Net application, with Entity Framework on it. Import is being made with EntityFramework BulkExtensions.

After 3-4 Imports, I receive TimeoutExceptions.

Some experts from my company reviewed my whole code. From Code-Side everything seems to be ok.

Now I have taken a look to the SQL Server. It is running a SQL Server 2014 Professional.

After running the query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
       i.name AS IndexName, 
       indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent 
       FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), 
                                           NULL, 
                                           NULL,
                                           NULL, 
                                           'DETAILED') indexstats 
       INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.OBJECT_ID = indexstats.OBJECT_ID 
       WHERE indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30 
       AND i.index_id = indexstats.index_id
```

I got following Result:
[image: Result of the Query]

Now my question is, why is Index2 being created more than 1 time?
I have expected to get only one row for Table 2 with one Index (IX_Index2).

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the output - [sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql): "For an index, one row is returned for each level of the B-tree in each partition." - but you've not included anything in your output that would allow you to distinguish these rows from each other.

Comment: If you suspect indexes are the problem, is it feasible to simply drop the indexes before the import, and recreate once done - given you have a few hours before the records are needed?

Comment: @RichardDavis is there a possibility to drop or disable the index via Entity Framework?

Comment: What is the table and index DDL?  Timeouts are always client-side, what is your timeout setting, and how many rows are you loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question directly I'm afraid.

Regardless of your above query, you may want to consider dropping or disabling your index prior to the data load and then rebuilding / enabling it after the data load. This will *probably* be more efficient as otherwise the index will get updated as the data is being imported.

[This article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/disabling-vs-dropping-indexes/) provides some simple code to show you how to do this if you're not already doing so:

> To disable in index, issue an ALTER INDEX command.
>
> ```
> ALTER INDEX IX_IndexName ON Schema.TableName DISABLE; GO
> ```
>
> If you want to re-enable the index, you need to rebuild it – there is
>   no ALTER INDEX…ENABLE command. The rebuild works like this:
>
> ```
> ALTER INDEX IX_IndexName ON Schema.TableName REBUILD; GO
> ```
>
> To drop a clustered or nonclustered index, issue a DROP INDEX command.
>
> ```
> DROP INDEX IndexName ON Schema.TableName; GO
> ```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. But do you know, is it possible to disable the index via Entity Framework? I think the problem is, when I run the query from code, I will get again TimeoutExceptions, because disabling or rebuilding Indexes takes more than 1 minute on the SQL Server

Comment: if you're loading that scale of data you may want to set the timeout to `0` (unlimited), regarding indexes in EF, i've not done this myself, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862208/how-to-drop-unique-index-with-entity-framework-code-first-migrations, otherwise you should be able to execute custom sql to do the job.